# What's the first movie with a plot twist?

Tags: first-appearance, cinema-history

[The first narrative movie ever was *Trip to the moon* of Georges Mélièrs](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42179/what-is-the-worlds-first-movie/42182#42182).

It's about men going to the moon and fighting aliens, so a classical sci-fi movie but without any plot twists.

What was the movie with a plot twist?

Comment: Possibly _The Face at the Window_ , or _Quo Vadis?_, both from 1913.

Comment: Surely there are early silent films about the life of Jesus, which has a twist ending from the perspective of the Romans: (spoiler alert) *they knew not what they did*, and surprise, next thing you know barely three centuries later the Roman empire is in the hands of Christians.

Comment: There were quiet some movies before 1895. How you think that one was the worlds first movie? https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/42182/20039

Comment: @Zaibis Thanks for the correction, I believed an old french myth that it was the very fist movie ever (even harder not to believe it when you work at La Ciotat where they put allusion to "VERY FIRST MOVIE EVER MADE WAS DONE HERE" everywhere)

Comment: @Cascabel If those contain plot twists perhaps you should post it as an answer! :)

Comment: @Zaibis OP says "first *narrative* movie"

Comment: @poepje I actually said that thanks to Zaibis that corrected me with a link to the answer of "first movie ever made"

Comment: @sh5164 Ah, I see you edited your original question, got it ;)

Answer (score 39):

I don't know if it was *the* earliest, but certainly one of the earliest plot twists (and the earliest notable one that I know of) was the ending of *[The Cabinet of Doctor Caligari (1920)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cabinet_of_Dr._Caligari)*. The film uses the framing device of a man named Francis sitting on a bench with another man, telling him the story of his encounter with the villainous Dr. Caligari and his assistant Cesare.

Century-old spoiler incoming:

> The ending reveals that Francis and the other man are merely patients in a mental asylum; "Cesare" is also a patient, and "Dr. Caligari" is merely the benign director of the asylum. The whole story was nothing more than Francis' delusion.

That said, plot twists are so universal in storytelling (dating all the way back to *Arabian Nights*, and probably even earlier), that I wouldn't be surprised if there's an even earlier example.

Comment: Really nice answer, I'll still wait to see if there's a confirmation for very first plot twist before confirming this

Comment: The plot sounds similar to Shutter Island.

Comment: @Nav I've never seen Shutter Island, but Dr. Caligari is by no means the only film to use this kind of twist ending.